# Removing gravity from a non-orthogonal body

Tags: signal-analysis

I am not sure where to post this question, if it is not appropriate here can you suggest where shallI post it to?

Question:

I have a Cube with dimension of x,y,z. I am trying to do some integration to the accelerometer value. The problem I have now is that I can't assume that I should remove the gravity of 9.81m/s^2  from say in my case, Y direction only, because when moving in a non orthogonal line, the gravity is activity not only on Y, but also in  X and Z.

[image: Perfect movement where gravity only acting on Y]

[image: My movement]

(TOP) How the perfect movement should have therefore gravity in only Y direction
(BOTTOM) Real movement

I have an Euler angle to estimate the amount of rotation from each axis, but I am not sure on how to deduct the gravity accurately in this case.

Comment: From a single 3D accelerometer you can either derive total acceleration (or a vector of acceleration) or angle, assuming that the body is at rest. You cannot achieve 6 degrees of freedom with 1 linear accelerometer.

Comment: I've seen Madgwick's AHRS algorithm to rotate body to Earth frame. But I do not know how to use them, could you explain it to me in case you know? http://x-io.co.uk/open-source-ahrs-with-x-imu/

Comment: I am sorry, I have not found some time to go through any other resources from the provided link, other than the video. The video demonstrates a 3 DOF system that only recognises rotation, NOT (rotation AND translation). This is trivial to do with a 3D linear accelerometer by detecting the gravity vector and possibly adding a Kalman filter. The resource seems to include code. How far have you got trying to create a proof of concept with your hardware?